# How to embed a zoomed portion of a FITS image in the same plot with APLpy

Tags: python, matplotlib, fits, aplpy

I want to embed a zoomed portion of a FITS image in the same plot with [APLpy](http://aplpy.github.io/).

But when loading a FITS file with APLpy, there is only a 'FITSFigure' object returned.

```
fig = aplpy.FITSFigure('tmp.fits', slices=[0,0])
```

Is it possible to make it work with zoomed_inset_axes like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583153/how-to-zoomed-a-portion-of-image-and-insert-in-the-same-plot-in-matplotlib) , or there are some other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may specify the figure to which to plot with aplpy. You can then get the axes inside the figure.

```
fig = plt.figure()
aplpyfig = aplpy.FITSFigure('tmp.fits', figure=fig)
axes = fig.get_axes()
```

From that point onwards you can work with that `axes` and use any of the methods that matplotlib offers to obtain insets.

Also see this question: [Aplpy multiplot dynamic axis sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718823/aplpy-multiplot-dynamic-axis-sharing)

Comment: Thank you ! I did not make it work with zoomed_inset_axes. But I got what I want with aplpy.FITSFigure('tmp.fits', figure=fig,suplot=[0.6,0.6,0.2,0.25])